# actor replying to non-actor

Tags: java, akka

I'm just beginning with AKKA and have a basic question about how non-actor code talks to actor code.

How can non-actor code call an actor and get a response ? I've tried calling the actor from the non-actor using `Patterns.ask` but this doesn't work because there is no 'sender' to which the actor can respond.

So how am I supposed to do it ?

Comment: Why not? What happens when you just call `getSender()` from your Actor? You should get the sender and be able to `tell()` it a message, regardless of the sender being an actor or not.

Answer (score 13):

This should work just fine.  When you use `ask`, a lightweight actor (I believe represented by a `PromiseActorRef`) is created to represent the sender so that a response can be sent back that will complete the `Future` that is created via `ask`.  A little example to show this in action.  First the test actor:

```
class TestActor extends UntypedActor{
  public TestActor(){

  }

  public void onReceive(Object msg){
    getContext().sender().tell("bar", getContext().self());
  }
}
```

Then the non-actor code that will call it

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import scala.concurrent.Await;
import scala.concurrent.Future;
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.pattern.Patterns;
import akka.util.Timeout;

public class AskTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ActorSystem sys = ActorSystem.apply("test");
    ActorRef ref = sys.actorOf(Props.create(TestActor.class), "mytest");        
    Timeout t = new Timeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Future<Object> fut = Patterns.ask(ref, "foo", t);
    String response = (String)Await.result(fut, t.duration());
    System.out.println(response);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've found my mistake. I had forgotten that in my code the actor replies asynchronously to the non-actor (after delegating to child actors). This means that when I call getSender() this does not refer to the original caller. Doh !!!

Comment: @BillyBadBoy, if you are still having an issue with this approach, share an example of what you are doing and I can suggest a solution.  When the actor finishes the message it it currently processing, the sender will be nullified.  Once you hit the async point in your handling of the message, the actor assumes it's done processing that message.  You could always "trap" the sender ref before going into the async code (`final ActorRef originator = getContext().sender();`) and then `tell` back on that ref instead.

Comment: It's OK now thanks. I just needed to store the `ActorRef` of the original caller and `tell` it later.